# C++ compiler may does NRVO for single return value. How to hint compiler to do similar things for std::tuple and std::tie?

Tags: c++

I want to return multiple values and I'm curious about the overhead of using tuple to pack and then using tie to unpack.

I found that the compiler doesn't optimize for `std::tie` as I thought. Here is my code for experiments:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {
        cout << "   constructor of " << this << endl;
    };
    
    ~Foo() {
        cout << "   destructor of " << this << endl;
    };

    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;

    Foo(Foo&& other) {
        cout << "   move constructor from " << &other << " to " << this << endl; 
    };
    
    Foo& operator=(Foo&& other) {
        cout << "   move assignment from " << &other << " to " << this << endl;
        return *this;
    };
    
    void doSomething()
    {
        cout << "   do something" << endl;
    }
};

Foo Bar1()
{
    Foo tmp;
    tmp.doSomething();
    return tmp;
}

tuple<Foo, void*> Bar2()
{
    Foo tmp;
    tmp.doSomething();
    return make_tuple<Foo, void*>(move(tmp), nullptr);
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    
    cout << "Experiment #1:" << endl;
    f1 = Bar1();
    
    cout << "Experiment #2:" << endl;
    tie(f1, ignore) = Bar2();
    
    cout << "Finished" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
   constructor of 0x505330
Experiment #1:
   constructor of 0x505328
   do something
   move assignment from 0x505328 to 0x505330
   destructor of 0x505328
Experiment #2:
   constructor of 0x505310
   do something
   move constructor from 0x505310 to 0x505328
   destructor of 0x505310
   move assignment from 0x505328 to 0x505330
   destructor of 0x505328
Finished
   destructor of 0x505330
```

[C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/d3879f96) told me that the compiler does an NRVO for `Bar1()`:

```cpp
Foo Bar1()
{
  Foo tmp = Foo() /* NRVO variable */;
  tmp.doSomething();
  return Foo(static_cast<Foo &&>(tmp));
}
```

But for `Bar2()`, there isn't. Instead of using a move-assignment only, there is an extra move-construct.

**So I want to know is there a way to hint the compiler to remove the unnecessary move-construction? Or is it just impossible currently?**

By the way, the compiler shows an warning that there is an `unqualified call to 'std::move'` in `make_tuple<Foo, void*>(move(tmp), nullptr);`. Is there a way to get rid of this warning? Removing the `move` directly will lead to an error.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, leave optimazations to the compiler. It will already do the best it can.

Comment: Also there seems to be two questions here. First is hinting and second is silencing the warning. One question per post is recommended.

Comment: *Is there a way to get rid of this warning?* `move(tmp)` -> `std::move(tmp)`

Comment: `using namespace std` is bad practice. It may be reasonable to use in a mcve but your wording suggest that you're using it in your actual code. If you don't do that you won't have the warning in the first place.

Comment: Side note : Are you writing template code? If not don't use std::tuple, just take a little effort to declare your own struct with two members to add semantics and improve the readability and maintainability of your code (no more looking up what first and second actually mean). Ofcourse the same applies to std::tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Bar2` you don't return `tmp`, so Named **Return Value** Optimization can't be applied to it.

Instead you use `tmp` to initialize an anonymous `std::tuple`, which you then return.  RVO can be applied to the `std::tuple`, but since `tmp` isn't returned there's no such optimization that can be done.

---

If you really want to avoid any copies or moves, you could get rid of the extra variable and construct your `Foo` object directly in the `std::tuple`:

```
std::tuple<Foo, void*> Bar3()
{
    std::tuple<Foo, void*> ret{};
    std::get<0>(ret).doSomething(); // or bind std::get<0>(ret) to a reference, or...
    return ret;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bxx364qEY)

In this case, NRVO can be applied to `ret` because it's the object that the function returns.  There's no other object that needs to be copied or moved to construct the return value.

The major limitation of this is that you can't pass any parameters to the tuple elements' constructors.  `std::pair` has a `std::piecewise_construct` constructor to allow this, but no such constructor exists for `std::tuple`.